# Best way to return the exact python function just run as single repeatable string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a need, in certain functions, to output a string that provides a repeatable version of the function I just ran.

For example

```
def repeater(arg_a, kwarg_a = 1, kwrag_b = 'b', kwarg_d = {'a':'a'}):
    func_str = #My exact function with input args as a string
    print(func_str)
```

I would want running the following code:

```
repeater('foo')
```

To print the string:

> "repeater('foo', kwarg_a = 1, kwrag_b = 'b', kwarg_d = {'a':'a'})"

What is the simplest/most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: like `func_str = 'repeater({}, kwarg_a = {}, kwrag_b = {}, kwarg_d = {}'.format(arg_a, kwarg_a, kwrag_b, kwarg_d)` ? Also why?

Comment: Sort of, but I need the formatted string to look exactly like the one I gave here (quotes and all), or at least returned in such a way that you could literally copy the string as is, enter it in an interpreter, and re-run it. 

On the why: it's part of a tool that is run from a Qt UI where the users will need to be able to reproduce the results of the UI in scripts. When they press the "run" button, I need to output a string that they could copy and paste into their script to reproduce the results.

Comment: I don't fully understand, but think this is a bad idea because it sounds like you're encouraging them to `eval()` your output string; would be better to find another way; checkout the `unittest` module

Comment: Sure, I understand how this may be undesirable in many common developer situations. However, this is part of a 3D software pipeline where a standard part of the workflow is that users create things visually, and reproduce them through script. So when they run these creation tools through a UI, the UI needs to provide them with a command that they can copy and paste to reproduce the results in their scripted builds.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: import inspect

In [21]: def func_repr(frame):
    ...:     name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
    ...:     info = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    ...:     args = ['{}={!r}'.format(arg, info.locals[arg]) for arg in info.args]
    ...:     print('{}({})'.format(name, ', '.join(args)))
    ...:     

In [22]: def test(arg, foo):
    ...:     func_repr(inspect.currentframe())
    ...:     

In [23]: test(42, 'bla')
test(arg=42, foo='bla')
```

Comment: Awesome - this is *very* close, except that the output needs to be copy paste repeatable - so strings need to be formatted with quotes around them, etc.

Comment: !r should actually do this in the format string. I just missed to change the output line ;-)

Comment: @stowaway fixed

Comment: beautiful, simple.

Comment: @stowaway would you mind accepting this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, what a mess. The general approach I tried with a decorator seems really clunky, and I'm sure there are edge cases I'm missing. But, it works with the example, so here it is:

```
import inspect 
from functools import wraps

def get_method_call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    name = func.func_name

    argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    arg_length = len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults)

    kw_strings = []
    for kw_name, default in zip(argspec.args[arg_length:], argspec.defaults):
        called_value = kwargs.get(kw_name, default)
        kw_strings.append('{}={}'.format(kw_name, repr(called_value)))

    arg_string = ', '.join(list(map(repr, args)) + kw_strings)

    return '{}({})'.format(name, arg_string)


def print_when_called(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print get_method_call(func, *args, **kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@print_when_called
def repeater(arg_a, kwarg_a = 1, kwrag_b = 'b', kwarg_d = {'a':'a'}):
    pass


repeater('foo') # repeater('foo', kwarg_a=1, kwrag_b='b', kwarg_d={'a': 'a'})
```